# Swapping Words in 'Deep' Sayings

Tags: phrases, expressions, writing-style

Here's an example of a common swapping that happens when people want to sound profound:

```
The clothes don't make the man
It's the man that makes the clothes
```

What is this form of swapping called?

Answer (score 3):

It's a figure of speech called [chiasmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasmus)

**Edit**: or more precisely *antimetabole*.

Comment: Looks more like antimetabole to me. Though OP's example might be cross-dressing.

Comment: To quote from the article I linked to: "These examples are often quoted by modern commentators to demonstrate chiasmus, although they are defined as antimetabole in the classical sense." (though this is unreferenced in the article)

Comment: These modern commentators! Enough to give one indigestion. They probably don't care about their metabolism either. (Actually, isn't it the person who wants the correct term the one who wants to sound deep?) (The man who makes the clothes is usually called the tailor.)

Comment: @Edwin - You ought to to sew up your *antimetabole, cross-dressing*, and *tailor* comments into a single answer. I'd upvote it; you had me in stitches!

Comment: Is there a word for people who confuse chiasmus and antimetabole?